# How to look for file in all subdirectories and copy it?

Tags: python, loops, copy, subdirectory

I need a batch program that works like this after running it:

1. I input a number in batch window
2. It looks for a file called like input but with .tif extension in `C:/Print/`
3. If the file is not in `C:/Print/` then it should be looking for this file in all subdirectories, e.g. `C:/Print/64326/BCB/1234.tif`
4. After the file is found, it should be copied to `D:/HotFolder/`

I managed to create something like this, but first of all it doesn't work correctly and 2nd thing is that it's not universal.

```
import os, glob, time, shutil
os.chdir("C:/Print")
print("Scan the barcode.")
while True:
    barcode = input(">").upper()
    tif = f"{barcode}.tif"
    if os.path.isfile(tif):
        shutil.copy(tif, "D:/HotFolder//")
        print(f"File copied succesfully. {tif}")
        os.chdir("C:/Print/")
    elif not os.path.isfile(barcode):
        os.chdir(f"C:/Print/{barcode}")
        if os.path.isfile(tif):
            shutil.copy(tif, "D:/HotFolder/")
            print(f"File copied succesfully. {tif}")
            os.chdir("C:/Print/")
        elif not os.path.isfile(tif):
            os.chdir(f"C:/Print/{barcode}/FCB")
            if os.path.isfile(barcode):
                shutil.copy(tif, "D:/HotFolder/")
                print(f"File copied succesfully. {tif}")
                os.chdir("C:/Print/")
            elif not os.path.isfile(tif):
                os.chdir(f"C:/Print/{barcode}/FCS")
                if os.path.isfile(barcode):
                    shutil.copy(tif, "D:/HotFolder/")
                    print(f"File copied succesfully. {tif}")
                    os.chdir("C:/Print/")
                elif not os.path.isfile(tif):
                    os.chdir(f"C:/Print/{barcode}/BCB")
                    if os.path.isfile(barcode):
                        shutil.copy(tif, "D:/HotFolder/")
                        print(f"File copied succesfully. {tif}")
                        os.chdir("C:/Print/")
                    elif not os.path.isfile(tif):
                        os.chdir(f"C:/Print/{barcode}/BCS")
                        if os.path.isfile(barcode):
                            shutil.copy(tif, "D:/HotFolder/")
                            print(f"File copied succesfully. {tif}")
                            os.chdir("C:/Print/")
    else:
        print("Error.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a completely revised version of my original answer that was based on using the `os.walk()` function. It now uses the [`Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) subclass from the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module—which makes it almost identical to [@Andrei's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64668520/355230).

The principle difference being that I've incorporated the additional features you requested below in a comment.

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

root_dir = Path('C:/Print')
target_dir = Path('D:/HotFolder')
ext = '.tif'

while True:
    target_filename = (input("Barcode? ") + ext).casefold()

    for filename in root_dir.rglob('*' + ext):
        if filename.name.casefold() == target_filename:
            shutil.copy2(filename, target_dir)
            print(f'{filename.name} copied from {filename.parent} to {target_dir}')
            break  # Target found and copied.
    else:
        print(f'{target_filename} not found in {root_dir} directory')
```

Comment: That's very helpful. Can you please help me in adding 2 more things? I need to add a function on the beginning like "while True:" so the program stays open all the time and I can input multiple barcodes and the program won't stop until I close it manually? Also, can it look for files named like "52TgFsHH.tif" but the input is in lowercase? Basically it should ignore the case of letters.

Answer (score 0):

here is a small snippet:

```
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import copyfile

input_dir = "C:/Print/"
output_dir = "D:/HotFolder/"

barcode = "1234"

for filename in Path(input_dir).rglob("*.tif"):
    if filename.name == barcode + ".tif":
        copyfile(filename, Path(output_dir, filename.name))
        break
else:
    print("Not found")
```

Comment: Actually, one thing I noticed. It doesn't work if the filename contains letter. "123hb" doesn't work or "testfile" doesn't work. Any solutions to that?

Comment: Are names of the files in a same case?

Comment: Yes. The Names are the same case.